# How to modify output of {squarespace-headers} System Variable in square space template.

Tags: squarespace

When building a Squarespace template, The header meta data is typically outputted using the following, {squarespace-headers}
see
http://developers.squarespace.com/jsont-system-variables/,
If someone needed to modify the output of this especially the meta data, what would be the most logical approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can control the output of your Squarespace Meta or anyting else written by squarespace-headers easily using jQuery. This will allow for control of Search engine snippets on all pages. A feature which is difficult to modify in an ordinary Squarespace template. You can even insert this via the UI under the advanced area of page editor.

```
 {squarespace-headers}
    <script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"   integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script language="JavaScript">
jQuery('meta[name=description]').attr('content', 'Changed description');
jQuery('title').text('changed title');
```

Comment: I would definitely not recommend this. In many cases you'll find that the Search Engines don't index things properly. If you have an example, feel free to post and I'll check it out.

Comment: I believe this was an issue in the past but now Google will crawl the re-written titles and descriptions. I have had it work on one site so far. Will update on the next site I try it on.

Comment: @jasonbarone [Search results example](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Aandyberke.com&oq=site%3Aandyberke.com&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.3425j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) - All of these titles are re-written using that method and as you can see they are indexed by Google.

Answer (score 1):

The best the way to solve this is don't use {squarespace-headers}, plain and simple. I've spent an enormous amount of time trying to hack my way around Squarespace and ultimately I just rebuilt the {squarespace-headers} myself and dropped off much of the cruft you don't need. Obviously, this isn't recommended for production, but neither is modifying header meta with JavaScript :).

You can rebuild the meta completely using JSON-T.

Comment: I thought about doing that but was worried about updates breaking the site. I used the methodology I described below on a different CMS and Google crawled the re-written titles an displayed them in search results correctly.